# Как разбивать строку из формы Vue js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Подскажите, как исправить такую проблему:

Есть форма (поле ввода), со связкой v-model - это поле я вывожу в шаблоне посредством {{ text }}. Так вот, если строка очень длинная, как её можно ограничить? Т.е строка из формы просто идёт сплошником и не переносится, даже если установлена ограниченная ширина.

Пробовал max-width, width - не помогает.

**Когда строка из поле ввода короткая:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Если строка длинна, то происходит такое:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ограничение ширины не даёт никакого эффекта - как исправить?

Comment: Может это свойство подойдёт: `word-wrap: break-word;` или `word-break: break-all;`

Answer (score 0):

Ну к примеру можно и вот так.

```
// z - 31, a - 6, b - 20
"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz aaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
   .split(" ")
   .map(e => (e.length > 10 ? e.match(/.{1,10}/g) : e))
   .reduce((str, el) => str + (el instanceof Array ? el.join(" ") + " " : el + " "), "")
   .slice(0, -1);
```

Результатом будет

`'zzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzz z aaaaaa bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb'`

Comment: Вряд ли. Такое решение хорошо выглядит для подобных строк, где буквы одинаковые. 
Если будет текст с осмысленными словами, могут происходит коллизии и данный вариант будет просто обрубать слова.

Например вводить "Приветствуем Вас на нашем великолепном портале", то результатом по Вашему варианту будет следующие: "Приветству ем Вас на нашем великолепн ом портале"

Comment: Ежу понятно, что 10 символов я просто взял для наброски примера. В реалиях там можно запросто ставить 30 символов, в русском языке мне такие длинные слова не знакомы. И да именно поэтому там есть split по пробелам.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать вашему блоку - обертке `text-overflow: ellipsis;`.
Данное CSS свойство определяет параметры видимости текста в блоке, если текст целиком не помещается в заданную область.

Либо можете использовать встроенные возможности vue - фильтры:
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Тут можно менять содержимое как вздумается.